# How to find xcode build directory from the command line?

Tags: xcode4, automation, hudson

There are lots of questions/answers about controlling where to put the 'build' directory when building Xcode projects from the command line, but rather than trying to fight this is there a way to get the path that Xcode is using?

I know it puts the files in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/APPNAME-xxx/Build/` where xxx is some random-looking string. I want to be able to get this directory from the command line so that I can archive my `.app` and `.dSYM` files, and also re-sign and package my `.app` using `xcrun PackageApplication`, which I currently use to create an over-the-air installable version directly form the build-server (hudson).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From command line

```
xcodebuild -project yourproj.xcodeproj -showBuildSettings | grep TARGET_BUILD_DIR
```

Remove the grep pipe, to see a list of all build settings, and choose one that is most appropriate for what you are looking for

Answer (score 13):

**For workspace**

```
xcodebuild -scheme scheme-name -workspace proj.xcworkspace ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -sdk iphonesimulator -configuration Debug -showBuildSettings | grep -m 1 "BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR" | grep -oEi "\/.*"
```

**For Proj files**

```
xcodebuild -project yourproj.xcodeproj ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -sdk iphonesimulator -configuration Debug -showBuildSettings | grep -m 1 "BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR" | grep -oEi "\/.*"
```

Comment: Better solution than the accepted answer.